# Vanilla JavaScript async multiple xhr.open()

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest, ecmascript-5

I would like know how to handle multiple xhr requests with vanilla JS. I want to open multiple html templates and load the page when all of them are ready. when I use few `xhr.open()` requests it will only return 1 template:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function() {
    if(xhr.status === 200){
        storage.append(xhr.responseText);
    }
}
function getAsync(url) {
    xhr.open('get', url);
    xhr.send();
}
getAsync('localhost:3000/template1.html');
getAsync('localhost:3000/template2.html');
```

I understand that `.open()` only works 1 at a [time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open).
So is it possible to load all teamplates asynchronously or should I just load one after another in a synchronous matter? Also, I wonder,if I should create multiple `xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()` objects so that I could run multiple `.open()`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using one variable to define the `xhr` request, and using that variable twice, thus overriding the variable the second time. You need to create a loop and use `let xhr;` instead of `var xhr` as `let` has a block scope, so each instance in the loop will be independently defined.

i.e. something like

```
// Create iterable list of URLS
let urls = ['localhost:3000/template1.html', 'localhost:3000/template2.html'];

// Loop through URLs and perform request
for(let i=0; i<urls.length; i++) {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.onload = function() {
        if(xhr.status === 200){
            storage.append(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }

    xhr.open('get', urls[i]);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Oh okey, so that means for every concurrent request I will need to create a new `xhr` object. Just another question. Does `xhr` dispose of himself after it's used? Or should I manually release it from memory?

Comment: JavaScript should handle disposing of used objects automatically - it has in-built garbage collection (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management) so no need to do anything

Comment: OK. Thanks. I am gonna give it a go.